# Capture audio of non-active tab?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

Is it possible for a Chrome extension to capture the audio of *any* open tab, not just the currently active one? The [tabCapture API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabCapture) doesn't really address anything beyond the current tab, so it would seem that this isn't possible.

In the case that this functionality is not directly supported, are there any known workarounds? Perhaps changing the active tab to another tab, capturing the audio, and then changing it back to the original tab?

I just want to make sure that there isn't some simple solution lying around before I start attempting this rather hacky approach!

Answer (score 1):

Well, your extension certainly can continue to capture *after* it was invoked, even if the active tab changes.

However, you can't "cheat" the security restriction by changing the tab after being invoked. You need to be on the target tab when the user [does something to invoke your extension](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/activeTab#invoking-activeTab).